# Index.php does not load automatically when site is opened

Tags: .htaccess

I uploaded to my wordpress files, have gotten all the configuration issues straightened out and it now works fine, but only if I enter the full address - www.mydomain.com/index.php

If i try to enter just www.mydomain.com it does not load.

Why is it not automatically loading index.php when the site is accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess, so it looks something like this at the end:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php Index.php

# END WordPress
```

This htaccess snippit is based off the one Ian says is default for wordpress. It may vary for Plsek Panel. This is another page that could help: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/apache-htaccess/directory-index-for-plesk-for-linux

(This post *has* been edited beyond recognition from its original state)

Comment: Thanks, i added in .htaccess, but no result. My home page remains blank. I am using parallels Plesk Panel

Comment: Try this page out: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/plesk/plesk-10/plesk-10-client-side/directory-index-with-plesk

Comment: Or, try adding the middle line in without the <ifmodule> stuff to the .htaccess file

Comment: i added after RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L], but no result

Comment: i tried as per your instructions. but no result. it remains same

Comment: Have you restarted your web server service/daemon? It would have to reload the configuration changes for them to take effect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35859/discussion-between-raghu-and-shade)

Answer (score 0):

Default wordpress .htaccess is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Make sure to drop that into the same directory of your site that contains the `wp-content` etc. folder.

If that doesn't help, then check in your general settings to make sure that your website isn't pointing to /index.php etc. Example screen below:
[image]

Comment: yes, in general settings, it show only domain url alone.. no index.php at the end of url